# Error 500 when retrieving Clockify workspaces

Tags: clockify

When retrieving workspaces using the `GET /workspaces/` API endpoint, I’m getting the following error 500:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-18T05:48:29.740+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
    "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "path": "/workspaces/"
}
```

This is the request I'm sending:

```
curl -XGET -H 'X-Api-Key: <snip>' https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/
```

I hope this is trivial to resolve.

Comment: Can you post a full request you're making? URL, headers and body.

Comment: I've updated my question with the request, nothing complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works when using the API key generated on the settings page, i.e.:

```
curl -XGET -H 'X-Api-Key: WchCprB5h15WpmvB' https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/
```

(of course that is not a valid key, but I've posted it so you see the format).
Make sure you're not adding any additional formatting or using the wrong key. If you're using a JWT token you need 'X-Auth-Token' header instead.

Comment: The key I'm using works perfectly well for all other API calls I've tried, for instance, I can get all workspace users `https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/5bc5182ab079874554f1f440/users/` just fine, just not for retrieving the workspaces information. Any way to check the server logs to figure out what the issue may be?

Comment: curl -XGET -H 'X-Api-Key: W8************EM' https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/  Your example indeed does work with both API endpoints. Can you try again?

Comment: Not sure what was going on, either a typo somewhere in my code or something happening on the server, but it works again now... Thanks for your help.